# How to quickly query similar text through postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, similarity, postgresql-performance, postgresql-15

I need to query the top few texts that are most similar based on the input content.
The table structure is as follows：

```
create table documents (
    id                                 bigserial primary key,
    content                            text,
    content_similarity_tokens          text,
    content_index_tokens               text,
    index_tokens_vector tsvector generated always as (to_tsvector('simple', content_index_tokens)) stored
);

create index search_index_tokens_vector  on documents using gin (index_tokens_vector);
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
table documents comment:
    content: the content
    content_similarity_tokens:Content with punctuation removed
    content_index_tokens: tokenized text
    index_tokens_vector: vector storing content_index_tokens
```

It works very well when performing a full-text search on user-entered text, for example:

```
select * from documents where index_tokens_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('user input text tokens');
```

**But I encountered some problems when querying similar content.**

Directly use the similarity function to query, but the query speed is very slow when the amount of data is large.

```
select id, content, similarity(content, 'user input text') as sim
from documents
where similarity(content, 'user input text') > 0.7
order by sim desc;
```

So I tried another way, first segmenting the content entered by the user, and then filtering the data through the index_tokens_vector field before performing similarity matching.
eg:

```
select id, content, similarity(content, 'user input text') as sim
from documents
where index_tokens_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('user input text tokens')
  and similarity(content, 'user input text') > 0.7
order by sim desc;
```

It looks effective, but I still found some issues.

1.If the result set remains large after filtering through `where index_tokens_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('user input text tokens')`, the query speed will still be slow.

2.For example, in the database, the tokenization of `text1:'I am 18 years old'`  is `18 years old` and the user-input `text2: 'I am 19 years old'` is tokenized as `19 years old` Since the token `19` is not present in the tokens of `text1` this record will be filtered out. However, their similarity is very high.

```
select similarity('I am 18 years old', 'I am 19 years old') 
# similarity: 0.8
```

**So, How can I improve the query speed for similar content?**

Comment: There is no "magically do what I want". You have to define *very precisely* what you mean by "similar content". Note that full-text search is not usable for similarity search at all.

Comment: Use a proper index and operator (not function) for the similarity search: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103821/best-index-for-similarity-function